# Selecting a range of cells with pyexcel

Tags: python, pyexcel

I reviewed the pyexcel doc and I could not find any RANGE method as openpyxl has (I'm working with ods files). What I'm doing right now is a loop using sheet.row method. Any suggestion? Thanks!.

Comment: What operation are you performing in the loop that you would like to perform on the `range` instead?

Comment: @tony  I m not doing anything in the loop. I was looking for some method/function that gets the range.

Comment: Please have a look at [doc page](http://pyexcel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bigdata.html) and see if you get what you wanted.